# How to know when a key press event is triggered on certain element

Tags: jquery, dom, keypress

All:

I am pretty new to jQuery. My question about key press event is:

DIV 1 AREA
    
        DIV 2 AREA
        DIV 3 AREA

Unlike click event, it is hard to tell which element does that keypress event happend, so I wonder how can I tell difference when I specify .keypress() on body/#d1/#d2/#d3?

One user case I want to achieve is:

There are two input text boxes, 
**[1]** when none of them get focus, if user keypress triggered, the first textbox will automatically get focus and accept input,  **[2]** if we click the second text box to manually focus on it, then only it can accpet user input without triggering the first one to get focus.

I use `$(document).keypress(function(e){ $("input#firstinput").focus(); })` to achieve **[1]**

Current problem is about **[2]** no matter when I type in second input text box, it will always trigger the first textbox to get focus, I wonder how can I solve this problem by identify when does my keypress event happen?

Thanks

Comment: see this https://api.jquery.com/keypress/    in your case it will be $(<element>).keypress ...

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if second input isn't focused to set focus on first input on `keypress`

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (!$('.two').is(':focus')) $(".one").focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="one">
<input type="text" class="two">
```